# using jQuery to validate a series of radio buttons using looping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, each

So I'm setting up a quiz - each question has a series of 3 radio buttons. I want to use jQuery validation to make sure that the user has checked at least one answer per question.

Here's my HTML

```
    <!-- Question 1 -->
    <div class="large-12 questions" id="question-1">
      <h5>Question 1</h5>
      <label><input type="radio" name="radio-one" value="340,000">Answer</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="radio-one" value="6 million">Answer</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="radio-one" value="11 million" class="correct-answer">Answer</label>
    </div>

    <!-- Question 2 -->
    <div class="large-12 questions" id="question-2">
      <h5>Question 2</h5>
      <label><input type="radio" name="radio-two" value="1 in 2,000">Answer</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="radio-two" value="1 in 1,400">Answer</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="radio-two" value="1 in 500" class="correct-answer">Answer</label>
    </div>

    <!-- Question 3 -->
    <div class="large-12 questions" id="question-3">
      <h5>Question 3</h5>
      <label><input type="radio" name="radio-three" value="Every day">Answer</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="radio-three" value="Every 6 hours">Answer</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="radio-three" value="Every 83 minutes" class="correct-answer">Answer</label>
    </div>

    <!-- Question 4 -->
    <div class="large-12 questions" id="question-4">
      <h5>Question 4</h5>
      <label><input type="radio" name="radio-four" value="2%">Answer</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="radio-four" value="11%">Answer</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="radio-four" value="20%" class="correct-answer">Answer</label>
    </div>

    <!-- Question 5 -->
    <div class="large-12 questions" id="question-5">
      <h5>Question 5</h5>
      <label><input type="radio" name="radio-five" value="X%">Answer</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="radio-five" value="XX%" class="correct-answer">Answer</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="radio-five" value="X.X%">Answer</label>
    </div>
```

Here's my main.js code

```
    $('.questions').each(function(){
    if($('#question input:radio').is(':checked')){
        alert('this works');
    } else {
        alert('you missed one');
    }
```

When I run this code, if I leave one question 'unanswered' I'm getting 5 alerts saying "you missed one". How can I change my JavaScript so that if only one question is unanswered, it will alert the user?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is `#question` in markup?  It's not shown above.

Comment: @briansol good point - I went back and fixed that locally. I also came up with a small-scale solution; I set up a questionsAnswered counter, so each time a question is answered, questionsAnswered is incremented by ++. After, if questionsAnswered < 5, alert user, otherwise, continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `#question` doesn't exist. It should be `$(this).find('input:radio')`.
- you can alert missed question number using `alert('You missed ' + $(this).find('h5').text());`.

Full code:

```
$('.questions').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('input:radio').is(':checked')) {
        alert('This works ' + $(this).find('h5').text());
    } else {
        alert('You missed ' + $(this).find('h5').text());
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ax37hwp/).

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery `each` function will stop looping early if you return `false` from the callback. (This is similar to a `break` instruction in a normal loop.) If you update your error branch to

```
alert('you missed one');
return false;
```

then no other elements will be checked.

Answer (score 0):

To get only one alert message at a time use this code:

```
$('.questions').each(function(){
    if($(this).find('input[type="radio"]').is(':checked') === false){
        alert($(this).find('h5').text()+' is missed!');
        return false;
    }
```

});